# Pixate supports -webkit-border-image css property?

Tags: ios, css, pixate

Anybody knows if Pixate supports in the css the '-webkit-border-image' property?

I tried it but does not work.

There are other css framework to iOS that support it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but Pixate does not support `border-image`. [Here are the docs](http://pixate.github.io/pixate-freestyle-ios/style-reference/controls/uiview.html).

The only other CSS framework for iOS that I know of is [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui), and it does not support `border-image` either.

I suggest using an image to achieve the look you're going for. If you post more about it, I can try and make a more specific recommendation.

Good luck!